# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0') in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am making a minesweeper game and I want to save the mines around every field in a **two-dimensional** number array I tried it with this code:

```
let minesAround : number[][] = new Array<Array<number>>(config.fieldSize);

for (let col : number = 0; col < playingField.length; col++)
    for(let row : number = 0; row < playingField[0].length; col++){
        minesAround[col][row] = getNumOfMinesAround(playingField, col, row);
    }
```

but I get an *TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0') in Typescript* Error in the line:

```
minesAround[col][row] = getNumOfMinesAround(playingField, col, row);
```

I debugged the **getNumOfMinesAround** methode and it works without problems and returns a number.

**Edit**

The inner array is not in initialized how can I initialize it?[Debugging Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/natvc.png)

Comment: Think about what happens _initially_ when the array is empty

Comment: look into your `minesAround`, what does `minesAround[col]` return? It should return an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let minesAround : number[][] = new Array<Array<number>>(config.fieldSize);
```

This line only helps you to create 1st dimension but 2nd dimension's values are undefined like below

```
"minesAround": [
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined
  ]
```

You need to add the row dimension for `minesAround`

```
let minesAround : number[][] = new Array<Array<number>>(config.fieldSize);
for (let i = 0; i < minesAround.length; i++) {
    minesAround[i] = new Array(config.fieldSize)
}
```

The second problem is in your row loop

```
let row : number = 0; row < playingField[0].length; col++
```

It should be `row++` instead of `col++`

```
for (let col : number = 0; col < playingField.length; col++) {
    for(let row : number = 0; row < playingField[0].length; row++){
        minesAround[col][row] = getNumOfMinesAround(playingField, col, row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx but when I get this [error](https://imgur.com/a/uwqjNdN)

Comment: I think you need to use a proper bracket for the loop. You can try it out here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAtglgdiAzgQQE4HsCucAmEBcEcmUARiKgNoC6NEAvESAO4RqoCGAngDzvc9iZCgD4RACgCsASgDcAKHkRlERQDN0qCONCQAxumAEiJclsYAGWRANGeESddsBqZ9IgBvJStgIUGbBxKW2oGJlZ+Lilpb2UNVB1wCAxWQiEzMKtk9FZ7R2zmV3cvFVLoeCQ0LFxgw1oU0MZHWIgAX3l2+QM4REMQADpgdABzcV9KgNxpIA @HansPeter